# Issue with Copy only values when an event triggers

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

So I have a worksheet change even which will copy the row from one sheet to another destination sheet when the drop down in status column in source changes to `Complete` and later deletes the source row.

It works fine but, there are few cells which has formulas in source and it copies formulas rather than values. I know where is paste special but in my code I only use copy. Is there something I can do so that it only copies values from source and pasts in the destination.

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim Check As Range, r As Long, lastrow2 As Long, lastrow As Long
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False    
    lastrow = Worksheets("Open Projects").UsedRange.Rows.Count    
    For r = lastrow To 2 Step -1
        If Worksheets("Open Projects").Range("P" & r).Value = "Complete" Then
            Worksheets("Open Projects").Rows(r).Copy
            Destination:=Worksheets("Completed Projects").Range("A" & _
                Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
            Worksheets("Open Projects").Range("p" & r).EntireRow.Delete Shift:=xlUp
        End If
    Next r    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True    
End Sub
```

Comment: Try `Worksheets("Completed Projects").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(, Columns.Count).Value =  Worksheets("Open Projects").Rows(r).Value`.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Sorry but I could not guess with what code line should I replace this or this would be another new line. Could you please post the entire code including mine and your suggestion so that I can try. It would really be helpful

Comment: The `Copy` line: `Worksheets("Open Projects").Rows(r).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Completed Projects").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)`.